# I always get NULL as a answer in switch

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Zodiac { 
        public static void main(String[] args) {



            int M = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Month"));
            int D = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Day"));
            int Y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter year: (1900 - 2019): "));

            System.out.println("Date:"+M+ "/" +D+ "/" +Y);
            System.out.println("Month: "+M);
            System.out.println("Day: "+D);
            System.out.println("Year: "+Y);

            System.out.print("Your Zodiac Sign is: ");
            String animal = null ;

            if      ((M == 12 && D >= 22 && D <= 31) || (M ==  1 && D >= 1 && D <= 19))
                System.out.println("Capricorn");
            else if ((M ==  1 && D >= 20 && D <= 31) || (M ==  2 && D >= 1 && D <= 17))
                System.out.println("Aquarius");
            else if ((M ==  2 && D >= 18 && D <= 29) || (M ==  3 && D >= 1 && D <= 19))
                System.out.println("Pisces");
            else if ((M ==  3 && D >= 20 && D <= 31) || (M ==  4 && D >= 1 && D <= 19))
                System.out.println("Aries");
            else if ((M ==  4 && D >= 20 && D <= 30) || (M ==  5 && D >= 1 && D <= 20))
                System.out.println("Taurus");
            else if ((M ==  5 && D >= 21 && D <= 31) || (M ==  6 && D >= 1 && D <= 20))
                System.out.println("Gemini");
            else if ((M ==  6 && D >= 21 && D <= 30) || (M ==  7 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                System.out.println("Cancer");
            else if ((M ==  7 && D >= 23 && D <= 31) || (M ==  8 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                System.out.println("Leo");
            else if ((M ==  8 && D >= 23 && D <= 31) || (M ==  9 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                System.out.println("Virgo");
            else if ((M ==  9 && D >= 23 && D <= 30) || (M == 10 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                System.out.println("Libra");
            else if ((M == 10 && D >= 23 && D <= 31) || (M == 11 && D >= 1 && D <= 21))
                System.out.println("Scorpio");
            else if ((M == 11 && D >= 22 && D <= 30) || (M == 12 && D >= 1 && D <= 21))
                System.out.println("Sagittarius");
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid Date");

            {       

           switch (Y)

           {


           case 1:
           if ((Y == 1900)||( Y == 1912)||(Y == 1924 )||( Y == 1936 )||( Y ==1948 )
                ||( Y == 1960 )||( Y == 1972)||( Y == 1984)||( Y == 1996)||( Y == 2008 ))
               animal  = "Rat";
           case 2:
               if (Y == 1901||( Y ==1913 )||( Y ==1925 )||( Y ==1937 )||( Y ==1949 )
               ||( Y ==1961 )||( Y ==1973 )||( Y ==1985 )||( Y ==1997 )||( Y ==2009 ))
                   animal  = "Ox";
           case 3:
               if ((Y == 1902)||( Y ==1914 )||( Y ==1926 )||( Y ==1938 )||( Y ==1950 )
                ||( Y ==1962 )||( Y ==1973 )||( Y ==1985 )||(Y ==1998 )||( Y ==2010))
                   animal  = "Tiger";
           case 4:
               if ((Y == 1903)||( Y == 1915)||( Y== 1927)||( Y == 1939)||( Y == 1951)
                  ||( Y == 1963)||( Y == 1975)||( Y == 1987)||( Y == 1999)||( Y == 2011))
                   animal  = "Rabbit";
           case 5:
               if ((Y == 1904)||( Y == 1916)||( Y == 1928)||( Y == 1940)||( Y == 1952)
                       ||( Y == 1964)||( Y == 1976)||(Y== 1988)||( Y == 2000)||( Y == 2012))
                   animal  = "Dragon";
           case 6:
               if ((Y == 1905)||( Y== 1917)||( Y== 1929)||( Y == 1941)||( Y == 1953)||( Y == 1965)
                       ||( Y == 1977)||( Y == 1989)||( Y == 2001)||( Y == 2013))
                   animal  = "Snake";
           case 7:
               if ((Y == 1906)||( Y == 1918)||( Y == 1930)||( Y == 1942)||( Y == 1954)
                       ||( Y == 1966)||( Y == 1978)||( Y == 1990)||( Y == 2002)||( Y == 2014))
                   animal  = "Horse";
           case 8:  
               if ((Y == 1907)||( Y == 1919)||( Y == 1931)||( Y == 1943)||( Y == 1955)
                       ||( Y == 1967||( Y == 1979)||( Y == 1991)||( Y == 2003)||( Y == 2015)))             
                   animal  = "Sheep";
           case 9:
               if ((Y == 1908)||( Y == 1920)||( Y == 1932)||( Y == 1944)||( Y == 1956)
                       ||( Y == 1968)||( Y == 1980)||( Y == 1992)||( Y == 2004)||( Y == 2016))
                   animal  = "Monkey";
           case 10:
               if ((Y == 1909)||( Y == 1921)||( Y == 1933)||( Y == 1945)||( Y == 1957)
                       ||( Y == 1969)||( Y == 1981)||( Y == 1993)||( Y == 2005)||( Y == 2017))
                   animal  = "Rooster";
           case 11:
               if ((Y == 1910)||( Y == 1922)||( Y == 1934)||( Y == 1946)||( Y == 1958)
                       ||( Y == 1970)||( Y == 1982)||( Y == 1994)||( Y == 2006)||( Y == 2018))
                   animal  = "Dog";
           case 12:
               if ((Y == 1911)||( Y == 1923)||( Y == 1935)||( Y == 1947)||( Y == 1959)
                       ||( Y == 1971)||( Y == 1983)||( Y == 1995)||( Y == 2007)||( Y == 2019))
                   animal  = "Pig";

           break;

           }
           System.out.println("Your Chinese Calendar Animal: "+ animal);
        }

    }

}
```

Example:

```
Date:12/12/1948
Month: 12
Day: 12
Year: 1948
Your Zodiac Sign is: Sagittarius
Your Chinese Calendar Animal: null
```

Comment: You need to add a `break` statement in each case, or else it will "fall through": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: You should reconsider your design. You have bugs factory with all of these `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Jin, you cannot accept both answers, so you have to decide with one you like to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your switch case expects Y values of 1 to 12. So 1948 would not match any case.

Beside that, each `case` should end with `break` (even though that wouldn't change the output in your example).

You can simplify your code by eliminating the if statements :

```
       switch (Y%12)
       {
       case 4:
           animal  = "Rat";break;
       case 5:
               animal  = "Ox";break;
       case 6:
               animal  = "Tiger";break;
       case 7:
               animal  = "Rabbit";break;
       case 8:
               animal  = "Dragon";break;
       case 9:
               animal  = "Snake";break;
       case 10:
               animal  = "Horse";break;
       case 11:              
               animal  = "Sheep";break;
       case 0:
               animal  = "Monkey";break;
       case 1:
               animal  = "Rooster";break;
       case 2:
               animal  = "Dog";break;
       case 3:
               animal  = "Pig";break;
       }
       System.out.println("Your Chinese Calendar Animal: "+ animal);
    }
```

Or you can put the animals in an array and eliminate the switch statement :

```
String[] signs = {"Monkey","Rooster","Dog","Pig","Rat","Ox","Tiger","Rabbit","Dragon","Snake","Horse","Sheep"};
animal = signs[Y%12];
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is complately unreadable. That's why you are lost in it.

I'm sure that removing all the redundancy will help you to catch that kind of errors very quickly in the future. Invest in that.

My suggestions:

1. **Always use {}** braces with if/else statements to reduce ambiguous code!
2. **Use functions** to extract similar logic.
3. **Simplify your logic** as much as u can.
4. **Use break** in switch-case statements

After applying that you have:

```
// You need either switch or if/else here - not both
int mod = Y % 12;
switch (mod) {
case 8:
    animal = "Rat";
    break;
case 9:
    animal  = "Ox";
    break;
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix, just get rid of the case, and make the list all `if else` statements

```
if ((Y == 1900)||( Y == 1912)||(Y == 1924 )||( Y == 1936 )||( Y ==1948 )
                ||( Y == 1960 )||( Y == 1972)||( Y == 1984)||( Y == 1996)||( Y == 2008 )){
               animal  = "Rat";

}else  if (Y == 1901||( Y ==1913 )||( Y ==1925 )||( Y ==1937 )||( Y ==1949 )
               ||( Y ==1961 )||( Y ==1973 )||( Y ==1985 )||( Y ==1997 )||( Y ==2009 )){
                   animal  = "Ox";
}else if …
```

There is probably a more elegant mathematical formula to work out a reference value for the animal, then a case statement will be applicable.

Not mathematical elegant but does the job without messy ifs!

```
 while(y >1911){
    y = y-12;
 } 
 switch(y){
    case 1900 : animal = "Rat"; break;
    //etc…
    case default : "U wot m8"; break;
 }
```